# story.ts:480 Uncaught Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, I have this in my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import TemplateList from './components/TemplateList'
import TemplateDetails from './components/TemplateDetails'

function App() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" exact component={TemplateList} />
            <Route path="/template/:id" component={TemplateDetails} />
        </Routes>
    )
}

export default App
```

My goal to show a thumbnails of templates, and when click on it will go to template details.

I can't get the page to load or the route to work!

Comment: You need to wrap your routes with Router for example `BrowserRouter`

Comment: Can you share reference link please ?

Comment: For example: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_router.asp

Answer (score 1):

In your index.js you need to import:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
```

and you need to wrap the app in Router:

```
<Router>
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
</Router>
```